# How to fix jest coverage

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Code to be tested:

```
const scale = {
  healthy: {
    health: 50,
    label: 'healthy',
  },
  wounded: {
    health: 15,
    label: 'wounded',
  },
  critical: {
    health: 14,
    label: 'critical',
  },
};

export default function getScale(character) {
  for (const key in scale) {
    if (character.health === key.health) {
      return key.label;
    }
  }
}
```

Test code:

```
import getScale from '../scales.js';

test.each([
  [55, 'Маг', 'healthy'],
  [30, 'Эльф', 'wounded'],
  [10, 'Дварф', 'critical'],
])('testing scale func with %i health and %s name', ({ health, name, expectedLabel }) => {
  const result = getScale({ health, name });
  expect(result).toBe(expectedLabel);
});
```

what the console outputs:

```bash
> jest --coverage

 PASS  src/js/__tests__/scale.test.js
  √ testing scale func with 55 health and Маг name (1ms)
  √ testing scale func with 30 health and Эльф name
  √ testing scale func with 10 health and Дварф name

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 
 scales.js |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 18
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.093s
Ran all test suites.
```

I tried the following steps to see if converage changes

- moving return
- moving the result to a separate variable

Still 1 line remains uncovered.
I am trying to get 100% converage.

Comment: Questions must be entirely in English.

Comment: SO is an [English-only site]. Please either rewrite your question in English or ask at [ru.so].

Comment: @ave_mrk Is the "Code to be tested" the whole `scales.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Branch** coverage is on 50% because you do not provide a case were the condition on line 18 evaluates to `true`.

Try passing a `health` equal to one of the values you have in your `scales.js` file (meaning either `50`, `15` or `14`), so that the function can run line 19 too.

Example test file:

```js
import getScale from '../scales.js';

test.each([
  [50, 'Маг', 'healthy'],
  [30, 'Эльф', 'wounded'],
  [10, 'Дварф', 'critical'],
])('testing scale func with %i health and %s name', ({ health, name, expectedLabel }) => {
  const result = getScale({ health, name });
  expect(result).toBe(expectedLabel);
});
```